# HTML5 Canvas/JavaScript(Scrolling background/camera)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**EDIT: 09/18/15** Gets rid of that screen problem, but brings forth another, more annoying one. The screen constantly flashes on movement.

```
function drawMap(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(map, 0, 0);
    context.drawImage(playerSprite, currentFrame * playerWidth, iconState * playerHeight,
    playerWidth, playerHeight,xPosition, yPosition,playerWidth, playerHeight);
}

function move(x, y){
    xPosition += x; yPosition += y;
    context.translate(-x, -y);
    context.save();
    context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    context.clearRect(0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.restore();
}
```

My screen gets really messed up, idk why T.T, I'll post relevant code snippets below. Please help me pinpoint and solve this issue. Thanks!

http://s14.postimg.org/9vwgy59gx/dafuq.png

```
var mapX = 0, mapY = 0, mapXOffset = 0, mapYOffset = 0;

function move(x, y){xPosition += x; yPosition += y; context.translate(-x, -y)}
//context.translate is referring to the map canvas

function drawMap(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(map, mapX + mapXOffset, mapY + mapYOffset);
}
```

Part of a separate function:

```
    if(moving[38]) {faceDirection(38);move(0, -moveDistance); mapYOffset++}
    if(moving[40]) {faceDirection(40);move(0, moveDistance); mapYOffset--}  
    if(moving[39]) {faceDirection(39);move(moveDistance, 0);mapXOffset++}
    if(moving[37]) {faceDirection(37);move(-moveDistance,0);mapXOffset--}
```

These are the only times I've altered the map in any way/shape/form.

Comment: This appears to happen when you reach the map's limits. I.e if I go north and reach a place where the end of my map.png is reached, I'll get that. etc

Answer (score 0):

here is a function that I had written for a platformer game that I gave up on. I've tested it and it works. The camera margins are just how far the camera has scrolled.

```
function testForScrolling()
{
    var translateLeft = hero.x < leftCameraMargin
        && leftCameraMargin >= minCamX;
    var translateRight = hero.x + hero.width > rightCameraMargin
        && rightCameraMargin <= maxCamX;
    var translateUp = hero.y < topCameraMargin
        && topCameraMargin >= minCamY;
    var translateDown = hero.y + hero.width > bottomCameraMargin
        && bottomCameraMargin <= maxCamY;

    if (translateLeft)
    {
        leftCameraMargin -= hero.speed;
        rightCameraMargin -= hero.speed;
        translateCanvases(hero.speed, 0);
    }
    else if (translateRight)
    {
        leftCameraMargin += hero.speed;
        rightCameraMargin += hero.speed;
        translateCanvases(-1 * hero.speed, 0);
    }
    if (translateUp)
    {
        topCameraMargin -= hero.speed;
        bottomCameraMargin -= hero.speed;
        translateCanvases(0, hero.speed);
    }
    else if (translateDown)
    {
        topCameraMargin += hero.speed;
        bottomCameraMargin += hero.speed;
        translateCanvases(0, -1 * hero.speed);
    }
}
```